# Company name that is a plural noun, what's the correct verb agreement?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Imagine a company called Spicy Labs. A fictional company where you can go online and create and order custom spice mixes. On their website, which tagline would be correct:

"Spicy Labs **lets** you choose from over 50 carefully curated spices to create your own blend."

or should it be

"Spicy Labs **let** you choose from over 5o carefully curated spices..."?

If there's a difference in English dialects, I'd be curious about American and Canadian English.

Comment: Please see [Is a plural name singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535962/is-a-plural-name-singular-or-plural)

Comment: Thanks. That suggestion didn't come up in the search... maybe because it doesn't have "verb" in the title.